# Initialising an inherited class from an abstract class

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on an abstract class for an `OutlinedBorder`, and want to share its common functions (my app will use quite a few shapes with complex paths). Since `OutlinedBorder` requires you to implement `copyWith` and `scale`, I want to abstract this away, but to do so I'll need access to the implemented class.

Here's my abstract class:

```dart
abstract class SolidShapeBorder extends OutlinedBorder {
  const SolidShapeBorder({BorderSide side = BorderSide.none})
      : super(side: side);

  /// The aspect ratio of the shape
  double get aspectRatio;

  /// The width of the shape given a certain [height]
  double width(double height) => height / aspectRatio;

  Path _path(Rect size);

  @override
  OutlinedBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side}) {
    // return ?(side: side ?? this.side);
  }

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(side.width);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return _path(rect);
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return _path(rect);
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    switch (side.style) {
      case BorderStyle.none:
        break;
      case BorderStyle.solid:
        canvas.drawPath(
            _path(rect),
            Paint()
              ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
              ..color = Colors.black
              ..strokeWidth = 1.0);
    }
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) =>
      //  return ?(side: side.scale(t));
}
```

I want to do something like `class StarBorder extends SolidShapeBorder`, so `copyWith` and `scale` will need to return a StarBorder. Is this possible, or will I have to duplicate this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

*I want to abstract this away* Don't use function body, do like

```dart
  @override
  SolidShapeBorder copyWith({BorderSide? side});

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t);
```